# How to get suggested sublocality or locality

Tags: web-services, google-places-api

Sometimes google places api will suggest the locality e.g. '3524 51 Street Northwest' will suggest 'Edmonton' even though there is a sublocality called 'Mills Woods' returned in the address_components

Other times the api will suggest the sublocality e.g. '77 Finch Avenue East' will suggest 'North York' despite the fact that 'Toronto' is returned as the locality

How does the places api know which to use in the drop down and how can I use the one that the api suggests?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for contacting the Google Maps Platform Technical Support. My name is Thomas and I’ll be happy to help you with your question today.

The address that is displayed as the suggested address by JavaScript autocomplete widget is the 'name'  field of the object returned by autocomplete.getPlace(). There is also a 'formatted_address' field that is part of the object that is the exact full address of the autocompleted address.